# How are operational procedures developed?

Tags: nasa, esa, procedure, development

In anticipation of the upcoming Ingenuity flight, I have found myself wondering how procedures are developed by spacecraft operators.

How is a go/no go procedure created? How does the team create a operating procedure for the tasks that lead up to a critical moment? How is a checklist designed?

I am interested in the general methodology used for developing procedures, but answers may illustrate the methodology by referring to specific examples.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41737/6944

Comment: I've added the names of two space agencies that have a lot of deep space missions and whose procedures are likely to be publicly accessible and in English. We don't have a "space agency" tag (I thought we did!)

Answer (score 1):

One source worth reading is the [*Apollo Experience Report: The Role of Flight Mission Rules in Mission Preparation and Conduct*](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/tnD7822MissionRules.pdf), NASA Tech Note D-7822.

It's way too long to explain here, but a summary is that there is planning of the planning for the planning.  Best to simply read the report.